# Automate the Boring Stuff Chapter 5 Project - Chess Dictionary Validator

Tags: python, beginner, chess

First post, very new to programming. This is my solution for the chapter 5 project of Automate the Boring Stuff and I wondered if I am making any mistakes and is there a way to make it more efficient using what the book has taught thus far.

**The project description:**

> In this chapter, we used the dictionary value `{'1h': 'bking', '6c': 'wqueen', '2g': 'bbishop', '5h': 'bqueen', '3e': 'wking'}` to represent a chess board. Write a function named `isValidChessBoard()` that takes a dictionary argument and returns `True` or `False` depending on if the board is valid. A valid board will have exactly one black king and exactly one white king. Each player can only have at most 16 pieces, at most 8 pawns, and all pieces must be on a valid space from `'1a'` to `'8h'`; that is, a piece can’t be on space `'9z'`. The piece names begin with either a `'w'` or `'b'` to represent white or black, followed by `'pawn'`, `'knight'`, `'bishop'`, `'rook'`, `'queen'`, or `'king'`. This function should detect when a bug has resulted in an improper chess board.

**My code:**

```
MyBoard = {'a8': 'bR', 'b8': 'bN', 'c8': 'bB', 'd8': 'bK', 'e8': 'bQ', 'f8': 'bB', 'g8': 'bN', 'h8': 'bR',
           'a7': 'bp', 'b7': 'bp', 'c7': 'bp', 'd7': 'bp', 'e7': 'bp', 'f7': 'bp', 'g7': 'bp', 'h7': 'bp',
           'a6': '', 'b6': '', 'c6': '', 'd6': '', 'e6': '', 'f6': '', 'g6': '', 'h6': '',
           'a5': '', 'b5': '', 'c5': '', 'd5': '', 'e5': '', 'f5': '', 'g5': '', 'h5': '',
           'a4': '', 'b4': '', 'c4': '', 'd4': '', 'e4': '', 'f4': '', 'g4': '', 'h4': '',
           'a3': '', 'b3': '', 'c3': '', 'd3': '', 'e3': '', 'f3': '', 'g3': '', 'h3': '',
           'a2': 'wp', 'b2': 'wp', 'c2': 'wp', 'd2': 'wp', 'e2': 'wp', 'f2': 'wp', 'g2': 'wp', 'h2': 'wp',
           'a1': 'wR', 'b1': 'wN', 'c1': 'wB', 'd1': 'wQ', 'e1': 'wK', 'f1': 'wB', 'g1': 'wN', 'h1': 'wR'}



def isValidChessBoard(board):
    valid_count = True
    valid_position = True
    valid_board = True
    piece_count = {}
    black_pieces = 0
    white_pieces = 0
    board_pieces = list(board.values())
    position = list(board.keys())
    position_message = 'Correct position.'
    piececount_message = ''
    message = ''
    
    #Counting blacks and whites
    for i in board_pieces:
        if i == '':
           pass
        elif i[0] == 'b':
            black_pieces += 1
        elif i[0] == 'w':
            white_pieces += 1
        piececount_message = 'There are ' + str(white_pieces) + ' white pieces and ' + str(black_pieces) + ' black pieces.'
            
    #Checking valid position
    for p in position:
        position_str = int(p[1])
        if position_str > 8 or position_str < 1:
            valid_position = False
            position_message = 'Invalid position.'

    #Counting the number of each piece and setting default for empty spaces
    for v in MyBoard.values():
        piece_count.setdefault(v, 0)
        piece_count[v] += 1
    print(piece_count)

    #Checking King numbers
    if piece_count.get('wK', 0) > 1 or piece_count.get('bK', 0) > 1\
    or piece_count.get('wK', 0) < 1 or piece_count.get('bK', 0) < 1:
        valid_count = False
        message = 'King count error.'

    #Checking Queen numbers
    elif piece_count.get('wQ', 0) > 1 or piece_count.get('bQ', 0) > 1\
    or piece_count.get('wQ', 0) < 1 or piece_count.get('bQ', 0) < 1:
        valid_count = False
        message = 'Queen count Error.'

    #Checking Bishop numbers
    elif piece_count.get('wB', 0) > 2 or piece_count.get('bB', 0) > 2\
    or piece_count.get('wB', 0) < 2 or piece_count.get('bB', 0) < 2:
        valid_count = False
        message = 'Bishop count error.'

    #Checking Knight numbers
    elif piece_count.get('wN', 0) > 2 or piece_count.get('bN', 0) > 2\
    or piece_count.get('wN', 0) < 2 or piece_count.get('bN', 0) < 2:
        valid_count = False
        message = 'Knight count error.'

    #Checking Rook numbers
    elif piece_count.get('wR', 0) > 2 or piece_count.get('bR', 0) > 2\
    or piece_count.get('wR', 0) < 2 or piece_count.get('bR', 0) < 2:
        valid_count = False
        message = 'Rook count error.'

    #Checking Pawn numbers
    elif piece_count.get('wp', 0) > 8 or piece_count.get('bp', 0) > 8\
    or piece_count.get('wp', 0) < 8 or piece_count.get('bp', 0) < 8:
        valid_count = False
        message = 'Pawn count error.'

    else:
        message = 'Correct number of pieces on the board.'

    valid_board = valid_count and valid_position
    print(piececount_message)
    print(position_message)
    print(message)
    print('Board Valid: ' + str(valid_board) + '.')
    


isValidChessBoard(MyBoard)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation has broken the spec. Pieces aren't supposed to have a single letter to identify them; they're supposed to have the full word.

Your `message` and `print` code is non-ideal because:

- it complicates your implementation;
- it wasn't asked for in the spec; and
- it forces all callers to produce console output whether they wanted it or not.

So it should go away.

Your `# Checking ... numbers` code is repetitive and can be simplified by use of a lookup dictionary for expected counts of each piece.

Another way that you've broken the spec - re-read this section:

> returns `True` or `False` depending on if the board is valid

Your function does not return.

Otherwise, consider:

- Add type hints
- Make a simple object-oriented interface for a `Piece`

### Suggested

```
from typing import NamedTuple, Iterator, Literal


class Piece(NamedTuple):
    row: Literal['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
    col: Literal['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
    player: Literal['b', 'w']
    piece: Literal['pawn', 'knight', 'bishop', 'rook', 'queen', 'king']

    @classmethod
    def from_pair(cls, pos: str, piece: str) -> 'Piece':
        row, col = pos
        return cls(row=row, col=col, player=piece[0], piece=piece[1:])

    @property
    def is_valid(self) -> bool:
        return (
            # all pieces must be on a valid space from '1a' to '8h'; that is, a piece can’t be on space '9z'.
            self.row in {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'}
            and self.col in {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'}
            # The piece names begin with either a 'w' or 'b' to represent white or black
            and self.player in {'b','w'}
            # followed by 'pawn', 'knight', 'bishop', 'rook', 'queen', or 'king'
            and self.piece in {'pawn', 'knight', 'bishop', 'rook', 'queen', 'king'}
        )


def parse_pieces(board: dict[str, str]) -> Iterator[Piece]:
    for pos, player_piece in board.items():
        if player_piece != '':
            yield Piece.from_pair(pos, player_piece)


def is_valid_chess_board(board: dict[str, str]) -> bool:
    try:
        pieces = list(parse_pieces(board))
    except IndexError:
        return False

    if not all(piece.is_valid for piece in pieces):
        return False

    counts = {
        'pawn': 8, 'knight': 2, 'bishop': 2, 'rook': 2, 'queen': 1, 'king': 1,
    }

    for player in 'bw':
        for piece_name, piece_count in counts.items():
            count = sum(
                piece.player == player and piece.piece == piece_name
                for piece in pieces
            )
            if count != piece_count:
                return False

    return True


def main() -> None:
    my_board = {
        'a8': 'brook', 'b8': 'bknight', 'c8': 'bbishop', 'd8':  'bking', 'e8': 'bqueen', 'f8': 'bbishop', 'g8': 'bknight', 'h8': 'brook',
        'a7': 'bpawn', 'b7':   'bpawn', 'c7':   'bpawn', 'd7':  'bpawn', 'e7':  'bpawn', 'f7':   'bpawn', 'g7':   'bpawn', 'h7': 'bpawn',
        'a6':      '', 'b6':        '', 'c6':        '', 'd6':       '', 'e6':       '', 'f6':        '', 'g6':        '', 'h6':      '',
        'a5':      '', 'b5':        '', 'c5':        '', 'd5':       '', 'e5':       '', 'f5':        '', 'g5':        '', 'h5':      '',
        'a4':      '', 'b4':        '', 'c4':        '', 'd4':       '', 'e4':       '', 'f4':        '', 'g4':        '', 'h4':      '',
        'a3':      '', 'b3':        '', 'c3':        '', 'd3':       '', 'e3':       '', 'f3':        '', 'g3':        '', 'h3':      '',
        'a2': 'wpawn', 'b2':   'wpawn', 'c2':   'wpawn', 'd2':  'wpawn', 'e2':  'wpawn', 'f2':   'wpawn', 'g2':   'wpawn', 'h2': 'wpawn',
        'a1': 'wrook', 'b1': 'wknight', 'c1': 'wbishop', 'd1': 'wqueen', 'e1':  'wking', 'f1': 'wbishop', 'g1': 'wknight', 'h1': 'wrook',
    }

    print(is_valid_chess_board(my_board))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: For the piece names I purposefully broke that to make it closer to the algebraic notation that chess uses. For the rest, thank you!